# Overview of game theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, big-list

I have a good high school math background, and I am interested in game theory, so I wanted to know something more about it, but I found very technical things or wikipedia. I am looking for something in the middle: a general (free), basic, but interesting and correct, and not long overview of game theory (most preferably an handout rather that a book) written by experts. What do you suggest?

Comment: wikipedia would probably give a general overview

Comment: The request needs more context.  What (mathematical) background do you have?  What do you consider "basic" game theory?  What did you already read or attempt before asking for suggestions here?

Comment: I have a good high school math background, and I am interested about game theory, so I wanted to know something more about it, but I found very technical things or wikipedia. I wanted something in the middle, something introductory. I think that Stanford Enciclopedia will do (plus, as Nick pointed out, it has a nice bibliography, in case I want to go a bit further). What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article on the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/game-theory/): it should satisfy your needs. Furthermore, it has a well-selected bibliography.

Comment: Good. Thank you for the fast reply. It was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Why exactly was this answer downvoted? The poster answered the question as asked...

Comment: Reading the [article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/game-theory/), I came across the concept of altruism and I got really interested. Any further reading on that?

Comment: Well, if you are searching for a good introduction, I think that you should have a look at [this](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/altruism-biological/) great article by Professor Samir Okasha.

Comment: Seems cool (I took a course in biology too!). Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.